# Stored procedure ignoring Nulls and fetch result for only entered parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure to do a search through a table. I have many different search columns, all of which are optional. Is there a way to create a stored procedure that will handle this? Let's say I have a table with four columns ID, N1, N2 and N3. I could do something like this:

Table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sample]
VALUES ('1', 'A,B,C', 'A,B,C', 'A,B,C'),
       ('2', 'B,D,N', 'B,D,N', 'B,D,N'),
       ('3', 'A,N,S', 'A,N,S', 'A,N,S'),
       ('4', 'S,F,G', 'S,F,G', 'S,F,G'),
       ('5', 'D,F,K', 'D,F,K', 'D,F,K'),
       ('6', 'S,H,Y', 'S,H,Y', 'S,H,Y'),
       ('7', 'Z,B,C', 'Z,B,C', 'Z,B,C')
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sample2
    @n11 varchar(max) = null,  
    @n12 varchar(max) = null,
    @n21 varchar(max) = null,
    @n22 varchar(max) = null,
    @n31 varchar(max) = null,
    @n32 varchar(max) = null
AS        
BEGIN      
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Sample
    WHERE 
        (@n11 IS NULL OR Sample.N1 LIKE '%' + @n11 + '%' 
         OR @n12 IS NULL OR Sample.N1 LIKE '%' + @n12 + '%')
        AND (@n21 IS NULL OR Sample.N2 LIKE '%' + @n21 + '%' 
             OR @n22 IS NULL OR Sample.N2 LIKE '%' + @n22 + '%')
        AND (@n31 IS NULL OR Sample.N3 LIKE '%' + @n31 + '%' 
             OR @n32 IS NULL OR Sample.N3 LIKE '%' + @n32 + '%')
END
```

If user enters @n11 as A and leave the rest, since N1 contains A in 2 rows, output should be 2 but above query is providing 7. If a parameter is not specified, I need that to be ignored and pass the rest to where condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the next conditions from your stored procedure query:

`@n12 IS NULL`
`@n22 IS NULL`
`@n32 IS NULL`

As the above conditions are returning always true while there were sent when calling the procedure.

**Stored procedure code after modified:**

```
Alter Procedure dbo.Sample2
  @n11 varchar(max) = null,  
  @n12 varchar(max) = null,
  @n21 varchar(max) = null,
  @n22 varchar(max) = null,
  @n31 varchar(max) = null,
  @n32 varchar(max) = null
AS        
BEGIN      
  select count(*)
  from Sample
  where (@n11 IS NULL OR Sample.N1 LIKE '%'+@n11+'%' OR Sample.N1 LIKE '%'+@n12+'%')
  AND (@n21 IS NULL OR Sample.N2 LIKE '%'+@n21+'%' OR Sample.N2 LIKE '%'+@n22+'%')
  AND (@n31 IS NULL OR Sample.N3 LIKE '%'+@n31+'%' OR Sample.N3 LIKE '%'+@n32+'%')
END
```

Now while executing `exec dbo.Sample2 @n11 = 'A'` the output will be 2 instead of 7

Comment: Working Perfectly..Thanks a lot

Comment: @VijayKrishnaReddy you realise that with this solution, if you pass a value of `@n12` in but leave `@n11` as null you will get unfiltered results?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to `AND` every separate input condition e.g.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [Sample] S
WHERE (@n11 IS NULL OR S.N1 LIKE '%'+@n11+'%')
AND (@n12 IS NULL OR S.N1 LIKE '%'+@n12+'%')
AND (@n21 IS NULL OR S.N2 LIKE '%'+@n21+'%')
AND (@n22 IS NULL OR S.N2 LIKE '%'+@n22+'%')
AND (@n31 IS NULL OR S.N3 LIKE '%'+@n31+'%')
AND (@n32 IS NULL OR S.N3 LIKE '%'+@n32+'%')
```

Note the alias, which is the best practice way to avoid having to repeat a long table name all over the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  sum(iif(N1 like '%'+@N11+'%',1,0)  
    + iif(N1 like '%'+@N12+'%',1,0) 
    + iif(N2 like '%'+@N21+'%',1,0) 
    + iif(N2 like '%'+@N22+'%',1,0) 
    + iif(N3 like '%'+@N31+'%',1,0) 
    + iif(N3 like '%'+@N32+'%',1,0) 
  )
from Sample
```

Any `NULL` variables will be ignored.